# Can we add a CNAME for an EC2 in Cloud Formation Template when ec2s are created using auto scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, aws-cloudformation, confluent-platform

I am working with a kafka cluster on AWS, I would like to give each broker a CNAME so I can reference that rather than the IP address.

I know usually with an EC2 we can do this in the cloud formation template using something like this..

```
{
"Parameters": {
    "TestCname":{
        "Description": "The IpAddress for the MyInstance Ec2",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "domainName.com"            
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "MyInstanceCNAME": {
        "Type": "Custom::ResourceDNS",
          "Version": "1.0",
          "Properties": {                                            
            "ServiceToken": { "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:<Account_Num>:custom-resource" },
            "Resource": "CNAME",
            "CNAME": { "Ref": "TestCname" },
            "IpAddress" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyInstance", "PrivateIp" ]}
        }
    },
    "MyInstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "ImageId": "ami-a4c7edb2",
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro"}
    }
}
```

The problem is that with confluent quickstart script for AWS

https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-confluent-kafka/blob/master/templates/confluent-kafka.template

I initially thought the creation of the ec2s must be in the referenced templates eg.

```
Fn::Sub": "https://${QSS3BucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/${QSS3KeyPrefix}templates/nodegroup.template
```

But I couldn't see the instantation in that template either and have just discovered through a guy on my team that the ec2s are being created through auto scaling.

Can we add a CNAME and how is the question? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link to the other stacks? Are they behind ELBs?

Answer (score 3):

EC2 Autoscaling helps you setup scaling for your EC2 quickly. The EC2s controlled by this can be terminated or started depending on demand or schedules. Because of this, it does not make sense to reference to any particular EC2.

I would like to suggest two alternatives:

1. Using an AWS Elastic Load Balancer per group of EC2, each load balancer comes with its own domain but you can assign a [custom one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html#dns-associate-custom-elb) if you want. Reference the ELB domain afterwords.
2. Using an AWS Elastic Beanstalk per group of EC2, this will manage whats underneath for you including the AutoScaling group, Load balancer, EC2, etc. Again, you will have a domain out of the box and you can set your own custom domain. Reference the ELB domain afterwords.

Here is a small cloudformation snippet of how I assign a custom domain name to my ELB:

```
Resources:
  MyAppEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      # this one also becomes a part of the domain name
      EnvironmentName: !Join ['', [!Ref MyApp, '-env']]
      ApplicationName: !Ref MyApp
      TemplateName: !Ref ConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel: !Ref ApplicationVersion
  DNS:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    DependsOn: MyAppEnvironment
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: your.hosted.zone
      RecordSets:
      - Name: !Join ['.', [!Ref appName, !Ref domain]]
        Type: CNAME
        TTL: 900
        ResourceRecords: [!GetAtt [MyAppEnvironment, EndpointURL]]
```

Other elastic beanstalk snippets can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html).

Answer (score 2):

Because the instances are being created with an ASG they're unavailable as CloudFormation resources.

To overcome this you could:

- create a script to retrieve all the public IP addresses of the instances associated with the ASG and setup Route53 CNAMEs in your hosted
- alternatively if you want to keep using `Custom::ResourceDNS`, you could again retrieve the instance IP addresses and then pass them in to your CloudFormation stack as another parameter.

Comment: To be fair this doesn't really sound like an answer 

Comment: Is the issue that you can't get the IP address from the other stack?

Comment: Well the issue is i can't reference the ip from this cft because i would like to use that to set the CNAME. I'm not sure I have access to the other templates

Comment: Maybe that's what i need to do actually edit them templates, was thinking they were standardised but maybe not seen as they use the s3 bucket name?

Comment: When you create your stack are other stacks created using the referenced CFTs?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, really new to this stuff and i didnt create the stack I've just been asked to give cnames to the ec2s, so we can reference them from applications if the ip address changes. From what I am gathering though is that the collection of ec2s i view on amazon were originally created from a quick start script like the one i linked. I don't think anything else is created

Comment: Not at a PC so I'll have to dig into the template more tomorrow. However it's possible to reference resources in other stacks. ie. The EC2 instances you need. This might help you out - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html. I'll also update the answer with some more relevant into re. cross stack references.

Comment: Great I'll be at pc tomorrow too so will check out then, thanks!

Comment: new update, guy on my team has informed me that the ec2s are being created through auto scaling so he is not sure whether we can reference the instances. any ideas if there is still a way to give them a cname?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many brokers you need to spin up (I am not kafka-knowledgeable), but if it is a small set of brokers.....you can block a set of ENIs and attach them using the user-data script based on a pool of available ENIs. You can define a CNAME for the ENIs. Only limitation or risk is that you cannot enable the 'Delete on Termination' flag...else your ENI gets deleted too.